# What is the difference between new GoogleEarth(map) and google.earth.createInstance(....)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

What is the difference between `new GoogleEarth(map)` and `google.earth.createInstance(....)`?  We are trying to incorporate Google Earth into what is effectively a legacy application which does however use Google Maps.  When developed it seems they had Google Earth in mind as there is the following code snippet:

```
if (google.earth && google.earth.isInstalled()) {
  var ge = new GoogleEarth(map);
```

We have a menu-ing system for maps that adds selection based on map types and this adds an entry for Google Earth automatically; when chosen however despite the controls showing up just like for our other maps, we get only a white screen.

Alternately we have tried `google.earth.createInstance` and the interface seems different from the other map types (road, terrain, satellite).  For instance, to zoom it seems we must use `lookAt.setRange`.  Furthermore the Google Earth map does not get added to our menu but at least the map works.

Is `new GoogleEarth(map)` deprecated?  Is the instance returned by `google.earth.createInstance` no longer a bona fide "map type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between...

[google.earth.createInstance](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#a254273ac0c55aa92b41f05db38b04ade) is the method in the [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/) for creating the [GEPlugin object](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin).

`new GoogleEarth(map)` is the initialisation for the [GEPlugin object](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin) within the [google-maps-utility-library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/docs/reference.html). It is essentially allows you to create objects (markers, geometry) that persist when switching between the [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/) and [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).

> Is new GoogleEarth(map) deprecated?

[No](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/docs/reference.html). Here is a [working example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/examples/earth.html)

> Is the instance returned by google.earth.createInstance no longer a bona fide "map type"?

It is, and always was, the [GEPlugin object](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin) - it was never a "map type". I believe the "map type" used by the library for the earth layer is "GoogleEarthAPI".

Comment: The Google Earth API was deprecated and then turned off by Google in December 2015: https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2014/12/announcing-deprecation-of-google-earth.html